How to optimize quality selection within a budget?
I'm working on a problem where I need to create the best outfit consisting of 3 garments from different categories. I have a total of 60 garments distributed across 20 different candidate garments for each of the 3 categories.
Each garment has two scores: fit and price. The fit score represents how well the garment fits, and the price is self-explanatory. My goal is to create the best possible outfit within a budget of $2000.
Here's a brief outline of the data:

Each garment belongs to one of the 3 categories.
Each garment has a fit score and a price.

What would be the best algorithm or approach to solve this problem?
I also need to handle these additional challenges:

Excluding Low-Quality or Expensive Categories: If the best candidate in a category has a low fit score or if the category is too expensive, I want to exclude that category and consider only the remaining categories, but only if the initial solution is not satisfactory.
Flexible Budget: If no good outfit can be created within the $2000 budget, I want to allow a slight increase in the budget (e.g., up to 10%) to find a better solution rather than settling for a poor one, but only if the initial solution is not satisfactory.

Example Data:
garments = [
    {'category': 'top', 'fit': 10, 'price': 500},
    {'category': 'bottom', 'fit': 15, 'price': 700},
    {'category': 'accessory', 'fit': 5, 'price': 300},
    # ... more garments ...
]

categories = ['top', 'bottom', 'accessory']
budget = 2000
flexibility = 1.1  # Allow up to 10% increase in budget if necessary

Key Requirements:

Implement a dynamic programming solution to find the optimal outfit combination.
Evaluate each category separately to exclude those with low fit or high price only if the initial solution is poor.
Adjust the budget upwards slightly if a better solution can be found, but only if the initial solution is poor.

Could anyone suggest a detailed approach or pseudocode to tackle this problem, including the dynamic programming solution and handling the additional constraints?
Any help or pointers on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Can you add expected output to your question?

Please edit to clarify "I have a total of 60 garments distributed across 20 different candidate garments for each of the 3 categories." Regarding "flexible budget", solve for different budgets to produce a graph with budget on the X-axis and maximum fit score on the Y-axis.

The meaning of "initial solution is poor" needs to be defined.

If I understand the question correctly, you have 20x20x20=8000 possible choices of outfit? If so, enumerating all choices and picking the best by whatever (currently vague) requirements you have is the best algorithm.


Sort and filter the garments.
Set a dynamic programming data structure. Run it in O(N ^ 3) through categories, budgets and garments.
Then, find the optimal outfits from the dp data structure in O(N ^ 2).
Check and see the outfits are within the budget.

Code
def get_final_outfit(*args):
    def _sort_garments():
        return {c: sorted(filter(lambda x: x['category'] == c, Gs), key=lambda x: x['fit'], reverse=True) for c in Cs}

    def _set_dp():
        dp = [[{'fit': 0, 'price': 0, 'outfit': []} for _ in range(Bs + 1)] for _ in range(len(Cs))]
        for c, cat in enumerate(Cs):
            for b in range(1, Bs + 1):
                for gar in SGs[cat]:
                    if gar['price'] <= b:
                        nfit = dp[c][b - gar['price']]['fit'] + gar['fit']
                        npirce = dp[c][b - gar['price']]['price'] + gar['price']
                        if nfit > dp[c][b]['fit']:
                            dp[c][b] = {'fit': nfit, 'price': npirce,
                                        'outfit': dp[c][b - gar['price']]['outfit'] + [gar]}
        return dp

    def _find_optimal_outfit(dp):
        res, fit, price = [], 0, float('inf')
        for c in range(len(Cs)):
            for b in range(Bs + 1):
                if dp[c][b]['fit'] > fit or (dp[c][b]['fit'] == fit and dp[c][b]['price'] < price):
                    res = dp[c][b]['outfit']
                    fit = dp[c][b]['fit']
                    price = dp[c][b]['price']
        return res, fit, price

    def _set_budget():
        condition = fit > 0 and price <= Bs
        if not condition:
            for cat in Cs:
                if SGs[cat][0]['fit'] < 5 or SGs[cat][0]['price'] > 0.2 * Bs:
                    NGs = [g for g in NGs if g['category'] != cat]
                    Cs.remove(cat)
                    SGs.pop(cat)
            return get_final_outfit(NGs, Cs, int(Bs * Fs), Fs)
        return res

    Gs, Cs, Bs, Fs = args
    SGs = _sort_garments()
    dp = _set_dp()
    res, fit, price = _find_optimal_outfit(dp)
    return _set_budget()


garments = [
    {'category': 'top', 'fit': 10, 'price': 500},
    {'category': 'bottom', 'fit': 15, 'price': 700},
    {'category': 'accessory', 'fit': 5, 'price': 300}
]

categories = ['top', 'bottom', 'accessory']
budget = 2000
flexibility = 1.1

print(get_final_outfit(garments, categories, budget, flexibility))


Prints
[{'category': 'top', 'fit': 10, 'price': 500}, {'category': 'top', 'fit': 10, 'price': 500}, {'category': 'top', 'fit': 10, 'price': 500}, {'category': 'top', 'fit': 10, 'price': 500}]
